# В чем разница в между $scope.$watch и observers в rx-angular?

Tags: angularjs

Есть ли существенная разница между observers в rx-angular и обычным `$scope.$watch`? Чем они вообще отличаются?

Answer (score 1):

[Вот ссылока на ответ.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876112/difference-between-the-observe-and-watch-methods)

Если вкратце - то `watch();` мониторит scope, а `observe();` - атрибуты директивы (и использоваться, соответственно, может только в директивах).

Если честно, то зачем использовать именно `observe`, я не совсем представляю, т.к. `watch` отлично работает в директивах (ну если использовать в них `$scope`, конечно). Хотя может это плохой стиль, а я просто быдлокодер и не понимаю тонкостей angular'а. =)

Comment: судя по всему здесь имелись ввиду совсем другие observers.